# Civi Membership

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I am currently using Caldera forms that would make a contact into civi. I was wondering if there was a way for me to set up for me to add contacts to memberships once they enter the database. To my knowledge caldera doesn't have a membership processor. Can you add memberships to contacts if they join a group? Thank you for your time reading this.

Comment: can you clarify what constitutes a 'membership'? why not send them to a Contribution page that has a Membership block (civi speak for a 'membership page')

Comment: or explain what advantage using Caldera forms is giving you since it doesn't give you what you want?

Comment: or in other words, do you know that civicrm can provide you with a form tht will add a Contact and a Membership and a User all in one go?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused about your question. You might be able to achieve what you want using the CiviRules extension (found here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules with documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/).

But it sounds like you might have to develop / have someone develop the CiviAction *add membership*.